# How to loop addview for table row?

Tags: java, android, loops

I've write this code to add textview into table row, but I've problem for number of rows, what I've made the number of table rows is constant (5 rows) and what I want is the number of table rows is dynamic. So I want to loop this code but I don't know how. Can you teach me how to do that? thank you :)

here is the code:

```
   TableRow row0 = new TableRow(this);
    TableRow row1 = new TableRow(this);
    TableRow row2 = new TableRow(this);
    TableRow row3 = new TableRow(this);
    TableRow row4 = new TableRow(this);

    row0.addView(createTextView(listTipe.get(0).getType()));
    row1.addView(createTextView(listTipe.get(1).getType()));
    row2.addView(createTextView(listTipe.get(2).getType()));
    row3.addView(createTextView(listTipe.get(3).getType()));
    row4.addView(createTextView(listTipe.get(4).getType()));

    row0.addView(createTextView(listTotal1.get(0).getTotal()));
    row1.addView(createTextView(listTotal1.get(1).getTotal()));
    row2.addView(createTextView(listTotal1.get(2).getTotal()));
    row3.addView(createTextView(listTotal1.get(3).getTotal()));
    row4.addView(createTextView(listTotal1.get(4).getTotal()));

    row0.addView(createTextView(listTotal2.get(0).getTotal()));
    row1.addView(createTextView(listTotal2.get(1).getTotal()));
    row2.addView(createTextView(listTotal2.get(2).getTotal()));
    row3.addView(createTextView(listTotal2.get(3).getTotal()));
    row4.addView(createTextView(listTotal2.get(4).getTotal()));

    row0.addView(createTextView(listTotal3.get(0).getTotal()));
    row1.addView(createTextView(listTotal3.get(1).getTotal()));
    row2.addView(createTextView(listTotal3.get(2).getTotal()));
    row3.addView(createTextView(listTotal3.get(3).getTotal()));
    row4.addView(createTextView(listTotal3.get(4).getTotal()));

    row0.addView(createTextView(listUang1.get(0).getUang()));
    row1.addView(createTextView(listUang1.get(1).getUang()));
    row2.addView(createTextView(listUang1.get(2).getUang()));
    row3.addView(createTextView(listUang1.get(3).getUang()));
    row4.addView(createTextView(listUang1.get(4).getUang()));

    row0.addView(createTextView(listUang2.get(0).getUang()));
    row1.addView(createTextView(listUang2.get(1).getUang()));
    row2.addView(createTextView(listUang2.get(2).getUang()));
    row3.addView(createTextView(listUang2.get(3).getUang()));
    row4.addView(createTextView(listUang2.get(4).getUang()));

    row0.addView(createTextView(listUang3.get(0).getUang()));
    row1.addView(createTextView(listUang3.get(1).getUang()));
    row2.addView(createTextView(listUang3.get(2).getUang()));
    row3.addView(createTextView(listUang3.get(3).getUang()));
    row4.addView(createTextView(listUang3.get(4).getUang()));

    tableLayout.addView(row0);
    tableLayout.addView(row1);
    tableLayout.addView(row2);
    tableLayout.addView(row3);
    tableLayout.addView(row4);

  }

  private TextView createTextView(String text) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText(text);
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 15);
    textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    textView.setPadding(0, 0, 15, 0);
    return textView;

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
  tableRow.addView(createTextView(listTipe.get(i).getType());
  tableRow.addView(createTextView(listTotal1.get(i).getTotal()));
  tableRow.addView(createTextView(listTotal2.get(i).getTotal()));
  tableRow.addView(createTextView(listTotal3.get(i).getTotal()));
  tableRow.addView(createTextView(listTotal1.get(i).getUang()));
  tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
}
```